# Linq query SUM and COUNT

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, sum

I have a SQL Server `Order` table with two columns (`itemPriceType1` and `itemPriceType2`). I need to get the total count and the sum of the two columns in a Linq query or a lambda expression.

`Order` tTable

```
    SELECT *
      ,[userID] as id
      ,[itemPriceType1] as itemCost1
      ,[itemPriceType2] as itemCost2
  FROM order;
```

Query result:

[image]

Desired result:

I want to get the total COUNT and the total SUM.

Eg.

```
Count = 4
Sum = 700
```

My attempt

```
var result1 = (from col1 in db.Orders 
               where col1.itemPriceType1 != 0 
               select col1).Count();

var result2 = (from col1 in db.Orders 
               where col1.itemPriceType2 != 0 
               select col1).Count();

ViewBag.count = (result1+result2);
```

In the above query gives me the correct count which is 4. Question, how can I improve this query? And possibly get the sum as well?

Comment: What do you mean by sum? From your example it's unclear.  Can't figure out where to get 700 from the numbers provided.  Is it sum all of that are not 0 from both columns?

Comment: Example given makes the question confusing hard to understand. Please use correct example.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to perform operation on one property, perform on the other and add up both results:

To get the count:

```
var count = db.Orders.Count(o => o.itemPriceType1 != 0) + 
            db.Orders.Count(o => o.itemPriceType2 != 0);
```

And the sum:

```
var sum = db.Orders.Sum(o => o.itemPriceType1) + 
          db.Orders.Sum(o => o.itemPriceType2);
```